# Python 3.9 Looping Script as Windows Service Not Installing Until After Script Completes

Tags: python, windows

Installing my Python script, which has an infinite WHILE loop inside, as a Windows service and I noticed it will only install once the script itself completes. How can I utilize a WHILE loop in this scenario?

Blog for reference: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7318/python-as-a-windows-service/

app.py:

```
import time
import pyodbc 
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from datadog_api_client import ApiClient, Configuration
from datadog_api_client.v2.api.metrics_api import MetricsApi
from datadog_api_client.v2.model.metric_intake_type import MetricIntakeType
from datadog_api_client.v2.model.metric_payload import MetricPayload
from datadog_api_client.v2.model.metric_point import MetricPoint
from datadog_api_client.v2.model.metric_resource import MetricResource
from datadog_api_client.v2.model.metric_series import MetricSeries


while True:
    with pyodbc.connect(r'Driver=SQL Server;Server=dev;Database=dev;Trusted_Connection=yes;') as conn:
        DF = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT TOP 1 cast(cast(metric_value as float) as int) as metric_value, last_updated FROM table", conn)

    body = MetricPayload(
    series=[
        MetricSeries(
            metric="PythonTest",
            type=MetricIntakeType.UNSPECIFIED,
            points=[
                MetricPoint(
                    timestamp=int(datetime.now().timestamp()),#int(DF.last_updated),#
                    value=int(DF.metric_value),
                ),
            ],
            resources=[
                MetricResource(
                    name="server",
                    type="host",
                ),
            ],
        ),
    ],
)

    configuration = Configuration(
    api_key={
        "apiKeyAuth": "apiKEY"
    }
    )

    with ApiClient(configuration) as api_client:
        api_instance = MetricsApi(api_client)
        response = api_instance.submit_metrics(body=body)

    print(response)
    time.sleep(15)
```

MonitorImageService.py:

```
# Reference:
# Mastromatteo, D. (2018): https://thepythoncorner.com/posts/2018-08-01-how-to-create-a-windows-service-in-python/
import app
import time
from PythonService import PythonService

class MonitorImageService(PythonService):
    # Define the class variables
    _svc_name_ = "PythonTest"
    _svc_display_name_ = "PythonTest"
    _svc_description_ = "PythonTest"
    _exe_name_ = "C:\\Users\\user\\looptest\\Scripts\\pythonservice.exe"

    # Override the method to set the running condition
    def start(self):
        self.isrunning = True

    # Override the method to invalidate the running condition 
    # When the service is requested to be stopped.
    def stop(self):
        self.isrunning = False

    # Override the method to perform the service function
    def main(self):
        while self.isrunning:
            app.check_web_page_images()
            time.sleep(5)

# Use this condition to determine the execution context.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Handle the command line when run as a script
    MonitorImageService.parse_command_line()
```

PythonService.py:

```
# Reference:
# Mastromatteo, D. (2018): https://thepythoncorner.com/posts/2018-08-01-how-to-create-a-windows-service-in-python/
# Robinson, S. & Hammond, M. (2000). Python Programming on Win32. Sebastopol, CA: O'Reilly Media.
import win32event
import win32service
import win32serviceutil
from abc import ABC,abstractmethod
class PythonService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework, ABC):
    @classmethod
    def parse_command_line(cls):
        ''' Parse the command line '''
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(cls)
    # Override the method in the subclass to do something just before the service is stopped.
    @abstractmethod
    def stop(self):
        pass
    # Override the method in the subclass to do something at the service initialization.
    @abstractmethod
    def start(self):
        pass
    # Override the method in the subclass to perform actual service task.
    @abstractmethod
    def main(self):
        pass
    def __init__(self, args):
        ''' Class constructor'''
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        # Create an event which we will use to wait on.
        # The "service stop" request will set this event.
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0,None)
    def SvcStop(self):
        '''Called when the service is asked to stop'''
        # We may need to do something just before the service is stopped.
        self.stop()
        # Before we do anything, tell the SCM we are starting the stop process.
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        # And set my event.
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)
    def SvcDoRun(self):
        '''Called when the service is asked to start. The method handles the service functionality.'''
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_START_PENDING)
        # We may do something at the service initialization.
        self.start()
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_RUNNING)
        # Starts a worker loop waiting either for work to do or a notification to stop, pause, etc.
        self.main()
```

If I change the infinite loop to 10 loops, you can see the service gets created after the script executes:

[image]

[image]

Comment: After posting, I ended up trying out NSSM (https://nssm.cc/download) and was able to get my service up and running in 3 minutes.